# Efficient method to compute the $U$ statistic

Tags: r, performance, for-loop, math

Let x be a vector of length n, and y be a vector of length m, 
the U statistic is defined as:

[image]

How can I compute it without using the for loop in R?

Currently, I managed to reduce it to only one for loop, but it is still a time demanding procedure.

Comment: Is this the sum of if(x_i>y_j) then 1 else 0?

Comment: Yes. I couldn't figure out how to use TeX on this site. Sorry.

Comment: Only some Stackexchange sites support TeX, SO is not one of them unfortunately. Please see my answer below.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I couldn't formulate. (Unfortunately I cannot upvote your answer due to my low reputation score)

Comment: Glad this helped

Comment: There are more memory- and computation-efficient ways to compute this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Outer is nice to do such nested operations it applies the function to every combination of elements and returns a matrix.

```
sum(outer(x, y, ">"))
```

Answer (score 2):

This is similar to compute the AUC. There are efficient packages to do that:

```
U1 <- function(x, y) {
  sum(outer(x, y, ">"))
}

# devtools::install_github("privefl/bigstatsr")
U2 <- function(x, y) {      
  n <- length(x)
  m <- length(y)
  bigstatsr::AUC(c(x, y), rep(1:0, c(n, m))) * n * m
}

x <- rnorm(1e4)
y <- rnorm(1e3)
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  U1(x, y),
  U2(x, y)
)
all.equal(U1(x, y), U2(x, y))
```

Result:

```
Unit: milliseconds
     expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq       max neval cld
 U1(x, y) 207.441259 210.245571 215.022827 211.683981 214.707473 423.98014   100   b
 U2(x, y)   4.641516   5.037166   5.853701   5.154041   5.330179  21.99448   100  a
```

Note that, generally, it counts 0.5 when x_i and y_j are equals (this is what `bigstatsr::AUC` does here).